# How To Make Window Look More Modern

Tags: c++, windows

I have created a simple window using the Win32 API with C++. The window shows up fine, however, there is no styling to it and thus all the buttons and such on the window appear in the Windows 95/Me Style as oppose to the modern windows 7 look. So, how can I get this modern look?

I have tried using the xml ways stated in this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) microsoft documentation but the program does not compile. I believe this to be because I am using the MinGW compiler as oppose to the VC++ compiler but I could be wrong. In addition, I am now trying the SetWindowTheme function but I am unsure as to how this works and how to include.

Some Notes that may be causing the issue:

- I am not using any IDE, Just a MakeFile
- I am using the MinGW Compiler

Comment: You should be able to do a standalone manifest. Check out [Application Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) and specifically the **File Name Syntax** section. Also, why are you using MinGW instead of getting the Express version of Visual C++ from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)?

Comment: @NikBougalis Although I get the feeling it's irrelevant here, there are a lot of reasons to choose GCC through MinGW over VC++.  There are 19 of them on this page alone: http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/

Comment: @pwny Fair point, kinda. But the 2012 CTP is almost *ancient*.

Comment: @NikBougalis It is, but C++11 support isn't as far along in the latest VS2012 either IIRC.  Even when it is, the update cycle for the VS compiler is so long we'll be in the same situation again but with C++1y features.  Honestly, that's my only complaint with VS though.  I love the IDE

Comment: @NikBougalis I agree the IDE is fantastic but I feel as though the more VS get's updated - the more they push .net and you are certainly correct about 11 not being supported as much. The standalone manifest worked by the way, thanks.

Comment: ctl3d32.dll was a dll used in days past to provide the 3d look from windows 95 era look and feel. I am on a cell phone but would be interested in seeing your example code and build.

Comment: Yes please a sample of the code would be nice.

Comment: @MattDwarf - I also dislike the added dust that has accumulated in VS over the years. It's for just that reason and many, many, *many* more that I only use it in a last resort. I find Code::Blocks integrates seamlessly with MinGW on windows platforms and GCC on linux boxes. While ResEdit is great for wysiwyg designing of windows apps, they're by their very nature, unportable. I've since played with wxWidgets on XP, Win7, Linux Mint64 and linux for the Raspberry Pi. The same wxWidgets project builds on all 4 platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manifest file must be incorporated as a resource in your executable. That's something VS does almost automatically for you; it is possible to do with MinGW too, it's just a little more convoluted. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/), in the section "Enabling Visual Styles".

Although the tutorial shows a winxp look, don't worry; once visual styles are enabled, they'll show up as the native theme of your machine.